# Convert datetime to smalldatetime in sql insert query

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, sql-insert, smalldatetime

I have an INSERT query like this

```
INSERT INTO tna_temp_attendance VALUES('" + strEmpCode + "', CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, '" + dtDateTime.ToString() + "'), 0, " + _inOutMode.ToString() + ", null, 0, 'CHO-', '" + strMachine + "')
```

When I execute this query there is this error occurred
"**the conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value**"

Help Plz

My database has this table "**tna_temp_attendance**"
and its columns are

- Emp_id    **char(6)**
- Wdate     **smalldatetime**
- Is_read   **bit**
- Machine_Status    **bit**
- Process_Status    **bit**
- Is_Error  **bit**
- Loc_no    **char(4)**
- Ip    **varchar(16)**

Edit

I passed the date like this also

**CONVERT**(**SMALLDATETIME**, '" + Convert.ToDateTime(dtDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")) + "')

But it also not working

Comment: can you explain it a bit more plz,

Comment: please provide the final string which is going to run as a sql command

Comment: the final string is named as dtDateTime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally done it.
 I declared a string.

> - string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString();

Then convert it to DateTime

> DateTime ndt = Convert.ToDateTime(dt);

Then I used

> CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CONVERT(DATETIME, '" + ndt + "'))

And It Worked. Thanks guys

Answer (score -1):

Try to use ISO format to insert date into SQL server as below:

```
dtDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Comment: Sir I need both date and time to be inserted, is it possible to use "yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss" format

Comment: Yes, you can use that.

Comment: But it didn't work, when I use CONVERT(smalldatetime, '2015-01-01 08:11:01') It works fine, I need to pass my date variable instead of '2015-01-01 08:11:01'